# How to return an IEnumerable (from one class) AND normal model to a view (from another class)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to view a table with parameters based on what you select in the dropdown. Currently the partial view gives me errors.

Some edits I have made based upon the below answer:

Dropdown and its div to the partial view:

```
    @if (ViewBag.ProductGroup != null)
   {
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.selected_product_group, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selected_product_group, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductGroup, "id", "product_group"), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ProductDD" })
                            <div id="selectedProductGroup">
                                @Html.Partial("productpartial")
                                
          </div>
    }
```

the JS code:

```
   $("#ProductDD").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = this.value;
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetProduct", "Home")', { id: selectedValue }, function (result) {
            if (result) {
                $("#selectedProductGroup").html(result);
            }
        })
    })
```

In the Homecontroller:

```
    public ActionResult GetProduct(int Id)
    {
        List<ProductGroupParameter> productgroupparameteritems = new List<ProductGroupParameter>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnectionQualims))
        {
            string query = "select   id, parameter from ProductGroupParameters where product_group_id = " + Id;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        productgroupparameteritems.Add(new ProductGroupParameter
                        {
                            id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["id"]),
                            parameter = sdr["parameter"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return PartialView(productgroupparameteritems);   
    }
```

Partial View:

```
   @model List<Project.Models.ProductGroupParameter>
   <table class="table table-striped" style="width:85%" 
       align="center">
         <tr>
              <th>
                  @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.parameter)*@
    </th>

    <th>
        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.parameter)*@
    </th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.product_group_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.parameter)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: How about making the `IEnumerable<LAB.Models.class2>` a property on `class1`?

Comment: GetProducts return model not equal type of Model at PartialView

Comment: Okay, removed, but still dont work.

Comment: @Xerillio can you elaborate?

Comment: Model in PartialView is `List<Project.Models.ProductGroupParameter>` but  GetProducts return  `List<SelectListItem>` . they must be exactly the same.

Comment: Okay GetProduct is now returning the same list. I STILL get the same error.

Comment: @fl13 What is error? can you share

Answer (score 0):

You should use partialview and ajax to dynamically fetch the model in the same view.

```
@model LAB.Models.class1
    @if (ViewBag.ProductGroup != null)
    {
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.selected_product_group, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selected_product_group, new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductGroup, "id", "product_group"), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control",id="prdouctDropDown" })
    }
    <div id="selectedProductGroup">
      //selected product table on dropdown change
    </div>


@section Scripts{
  <script>
     $("#prdouctDropDown").change(function(){
        var selectedValue = this.value;
         //correct Controlller name replace Controller
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetProduct","Controller"',{id:selectedValue},function(result){
           if(result){
              $("#selectedProductGroup").html(result);
           }
        })
      })
  </script>
}
```

get selected product as Partial View

```
public ActionResult GetProduct(int id){
    var product = new List<LAB.Models.class2>()     
    return PartialView(product);    
}
```

selected product partial view :

```
@model List<LAB.Models.class2>()
    <table class="table table-striped" style="width:85%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ID)
            </th>
            //...
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           <tr>
             <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
             </td>
             //....
          </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Hi, where does GetProduct() fit into? Its not being called anywhere? And I can;t make a list of <LAB.Models.class2>()  and refer to it in the view, I get an error.

Comment: @fl13 this section is  `$.get("getProduct_url"` you should replace it with correct url

Comment: Hi, Can you please look at the above code. I changed as per your suggestion, but still get errors on loading the partial view ?

Comment: i have just updated. You could write Url of getProducts with @Url.Action.

Comment: Can you look at the code above thats been modified? I updated it and get this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Upon running the project. Not even selected anything yet.